# adding click event on line drawn in a mapview between 2 geopoint

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to draw a line between two geo point on mapview and want to add click event on that line. I know i can draw line between two geo point by overriding draw function and adding canvas .drawLine() to draw functon. but dont know how to add ontap or a click event.

Comment: have you got answer for this...if so help me...